# Constructor that takes a static temp table as input (Progress ABL)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a class who's main purpose revolves around a temp table. I want to make a constructor that takes an identical temp table as input.

So far the compiler chokes on any attempt to pass a temp table as a input parameter. If I use a table handle instead, it works. But I'd rather not copy from a dynamic table to a static one.

Progress wants the tables to match up at compile time, but I know they'll be the same - the're defined in a .i file.

Is there an easy way to line up the tables, or am I stuck parsing it out one field at a time?

Comment: Odds are you changed the .i and the compiler's cache is using two different versions of that .i for the class vs the calling program, and that's why you're getting compiler errors.

Comment: Can you post some code? Your idea seems pretty feasible. What did you mean you know they´ll be the same? If they´re static, they are the same at all times. Or am I misunderstanding anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like a charm to me.

```
CLASS Test.TTOO.TempTableWrapper:

    {Test/TTOO/ttCustomer.i}

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC TempTableWrapper (TABLE ttCustomer):

        FOR EACH ttCustomer:
            DISPLAY ttCustomer.CustNum ttCustomer.Name .
        END.

    END CONSTRUCTOR. 
END CLASS.
```

and the caller:

```
ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

USING Test.TTOO.* FROM PROPATH.

DEFINE VARIABLE oWrapper AS TempTableWrapper NO-UNDO .

{Test/TTOO/ttCustomer.i}

/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */

CREATE ttCustomer.
ASSIGN ttCustomer.CustNum = 42
       ttCustomer.Name    = "It works" .

oWrapper = NEW TempTableWrapper(TABLE ttCustomer )  .
```

You can also pass the temp-table by-ref:

```
oWrapper = NEW TempTableWrapper(TABLE ttCustomer BY-REFERENCE)  .
```

However, then the temp-table data is only availalbe during the constructor as BY-REFERENCE calls "overlap" the temp-table within the callee only for the duration of that call.

For permanent "BY-REFERENCE", use the BIND keyword on the call and the paramter - in which case the callee must define the temp-table as REFERENCE-ONLY.

Note, it's not required (although recommended at least by me) to define the temp-tables in include files. At runtime and compile time, the schemas just need to match.

When the compiler does not like your call, delete the classes r-code and recompile.

Comment: The trick here is that I need to copy the input table to an internal temp table. I keep getting an "unknown or ambiguous table" error

Comment: So that would be BY-VALUE (the opposite of BY-REFERENCE).The first two blocks of code-samples from above do exactly the same. The procedure creates a new instance of ttCustomer and the class keeps a private copy of it. Mind sharing some code?

Comment: Wait, it's really that simple? I don't have to copy from this:table to that:table? It just happens automagically? I did not find that fact anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: Yes - default parameter mode for temp-tables and ProDatasets is BY-VALUE, that is the callee receives a full copy of the temp-table.

Comment: That I knew, but I didn't think the table would persist in the object.